# How can I implement Vim's `undo line` command in Emacs' evil-mode?

Tags: evil, undo

From the *Vim User Manual*: *02.5*:

> There's a special version of the undo command, the "U" (undo line)
>   command. The undo line command undoes all the changes made on the last
>   line that was edited.  Typing this command twice cancels the preceding
>   "U".

How can I get this functionality when using evil-mode in Emacs? `U` currently does nothing.

Comment: Well, for starters, study the exact behavior.  "Undo all changes on the last line" sounds rather vague to me.  Next step would be looking into how undo-tree works and augmenting it for this feature, then you could just bind it to a key.

Answer (score 3):

`undo` (bound to `C-/`, `C-_`, and `C-x u` by default) will restrict its action to the active region, if there is one:

> In Transient Mark mode when the mark is active, only undo changes within
>   the current region.  Similarly, when not in Transient Mark mode, just C-u
>   as an argument limits undo to changes within the current region.

(from `C-h undo`)

That allows to you undo changes in any arbitrary contiguous block of text. Emacs includes `mark-paragraph` out of the box, bound to `M-h` by default. That means `M-h C-/` (followed by as many repetitions of `C-/` as you need) will progressively undo changes to the highlighted paragraph.

We don't have a `mark-line` function by default. You can mark the line 'by-hand' with: `C-a C-space C-e`, and then use `C-/` (or `C-x u` etc) to undo changes to just that line.

Moving to the beginning (`C-a`) or end (`C-e`) of the line, and setting the mark (`C-space`) are things that you do so frequently in Emacs that after a while it just becomes part of your muscle memory. Meaning, I wouldn't gain much by wrapping this up in a special-purpose function. However, you certainly could do that, and you might want to use the `mark-line` function from `misc-cmds` that @Charles mentioned to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `C-x u` undoes one change on the last line edited.  If you follow that with a command that breaks the undo sequence, like `C-f`, then hitting `C-x u` again will cancel that undo.

If you're looking to undo a change made to any arbitrary line, though, regardless of whether it is the last line edited, you can try out "selective undo".  Type `M-x mark-line`, then hit C-x u: hitting it repeatedly will take you through previous states of the line in the undo history, without touching the rest of the buffer.

Comment: `C-x u` is bound to `undo-tree-visualize` when using Evil, please describe the command you mean.

Comment: I don't think Emacs comes with a `mark-line` command. You probably wrote one yourself and forgot you had done it. (I wrote my own `mark-line` too: pretty useful!)

Comment: Hm, sorry for misleading.  I don't use `evil` (didn't realize the question was asking about it), and `mark-line` is available in Drew Adams' `misc-cmds` package, which I've had installed for a while.  Maybe somebody else can provide a better answer for `evil`.

Comment: On my system `C-x u` is bound to `undo`. Selecting a region before calling `undo` provides more fine-grained control over what changes to undo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick first attempt that leverages how undo behaves when the buffer is narrowed:

```
(defun undo-line ()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (when (buffer-modified-p) (undo))
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
      (while (buffer-modified-p)
        (undo-more 1)))))
```

Edit: This doesn't use evil / undo-tree, just the basic undo command. You can do the same but using undo-tree-undo instead:

```
(defun undo-line ()
  "Undo the previous change and any other changes made at the same time to the same line."
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (when (buffer-modified-p) (undo-tree-undo))
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
      (while (buffer-modified-p)
        (undo-tree-undo)))))
```